# How to use RestAssured with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, rest-assured

I am using `Spring 4` with `Spring Security 3.2`. The application is running perfectly so far. Now I am writing Test Cases for all the REST services using `MockMVC` and `RestAssured`.

I have a simple Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secure")
public class MyController{
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getAllMedia(){
        return "SECURE TEST COMPLETE";
    }
}
```

And I have a `spring-rest-servlet.xml` file which has `<mvc:annotation-driven />`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mp.web.controller.common" />
</beans>
```

And `spring-security-context.xml` looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans>
    <security:http create-session="stateless"
                   entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint"
                   authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <security:custom-filter ref="customRestFilter" 
                  position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/p/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/api/login**" 
             access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" requires-channel="https" />
    </security:http>
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
          class="com.mp.web.security.CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint" />
    <bean id="customRestFilter"
        class="com.mp.web.security.filter.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
        <constructor-arg name="authenticationManager"
                         ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="restAuthenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>
    <bean id="restAuthenticationProvider" 
          class="com.mp.web.security.auth.RestAuthenticationProvider" />
</beans>
```

The application is just working as expected but whey I run the test case the spring security filter does not execute `'customRestFilter'`

Here is my Test Class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration({"classpath:application-context.xml",
    "classpath:spring-rest-servlet.xml",
    "classpath:spring-security-context.xml"})
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

    @Autowired
    MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void init(){
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
                       .addFilter(springSecurityFilterChain).build();
    }

    @Test
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        given().mockMvc(mockMvc).standaloneSetup(myController)
                .header("Authorization", userHeaderToken) // Token for user
                .when().get("/secure")
                .then().log().body();
    }
}
```

The `userHeaderToken` is used to identify which from which user I got the request from and its all handled in `'customRestFilter'`. But my requests from Test case never come to the filter.

Can some one guide me how to get the request pass through that filter.

Thanks.